# Javascript get data from [object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: javascript, forms, onsubmit

```
function createChatbox (from) {
console.log(from); //from= Hola
var chatBoxId= from+ 'chatbox';
$('#privateChat').append('<div id="'+ chatBoxId +'" class="chatbox"></div>');
$('#' + chatBoxId).draggable({ handle: '.drag' });
$('#' + chatBoxId).append('<p id="titulo" class="drag">Chat privado con: '+ from +'</p> <div id="'+ from +'textchat" class="textchat"></div><form id="msgPrivate" onsubmit="return formSubmit('+ from +')"><input type="text" id="privateMsg" class="texto" required><input type="submit" class="boton" value="Enviar" class="btnLogIn" id="sendPrivate"> ');
}

function formSubmit (from) {
console.log("entro en formSubmit");
console.log("from es: " +from); //from= [object HTMLDivElement]
sendPrivateMessage(from);
return false;
}
```

and when it goes to formSubmit('+ from +') the from transforms into [object HTMLDivElement]
how can i get the data from this object?

Comment: we need to see where the from variable is set, not in the function, but in the bit before (the jquery part). Is it a string you are concatenating, or is it actually an HTMLDivElement?

Comment: plz dont put me a -1 in the answer.
the from before the submit is "Hola" and when it pass to formSubmit it transform into [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: I didn't put you the -1 :). Can you please edit the question showing a bit more code?

Comment: Do you have an element with the id of `from`?  How is `from` defined before the `.append`?

Comment: How are you executing `formSubmit`?  Can you show an example?

Comment: the formSubmit is inside the form with onsubmit:
$('#' + chatBoxId).append('<p id="titulo" class="drag">Chat privado con: '+ from +'</p> <div id="'+ from +'textchat" class="textchat"></div><form id="msgPrivate" onsubmit="return formSubmit('+ from +')"><input type="text" id="privateMsg" class="texto" required><input type="submit" class="boton" value="Enviar" class="btnLogIn" id="sendPrivate"> ');

Comment: @Gary: It's the form's `onSubmit`.

Comment: onsubmit="return formSubmit('+ from +')"

Answer (score 0):

the solution is this:

```
onsubmit="return formSubmit('+'\''+ from +'\''+')"
```

thanks!